# Adding domain name to a Vultr managed Wordpress website

Tags: wordpress, nginx, ubuntu

I have a managed Wordpress instance on Vultr. I was able to access the website fine with its ip address. Now after adding the domain, I can't access the website, "this site can't be reached, server IP address could not be found." The ip address does indeed redirect to the domain name though.

I've followed all the steps on the Vultr documentation, https://www.vultr.com/docs/install-lets-encrypt-ssl-on-one-click-wordpress-app?gclid=CjwKCAjw0vTtBRBREiwA3URt7iqQFmNPbr6H8pL70Oyc5ndqzhl2jp-DlhWfOC-MjsBOI6MAV46UPhoCGkgQAvD_BwE

I've changed the site url & home url in Wordpress, and followed all the steps provided in this vultr discussion as well, https://discuss.vultr.com/discussion/1869/how-to-change-wordpress-homepage-url-from-ip-address-to-the-domain-name

In Google domains, I have added both A and AAAA resource records.

What else have I missed?

Comment: Have you updated the nameservers?  Check the A record at https://intodns.com

Comment: I see the green check mark under name server a records, "Good. Every nameserver listed has A records. This is a must if you want to be found."

Comment: Most of the items are with green check mark with some blue exclamation marks and two red exclamation marks next to mx records and www a record.  Is the last one the problem?

Comment: Found out that i just needed to add www to the dns record. @Steve you helped me to discover this, thanks.